# 2015 Sentra tank does not fill up completely

Tags: sentra

My 2015 Sentra SV stops taking gas before it's full.  I know for sure it's not a problem with the gauge as I ran the car almost empty and could only fill up a little over 7 gallons, whereas the tank can take a little over 13 gallons.  I tried to fill up slowly but could only add another 1/2 a gallon or so before gas started overflowing from the tank.  I would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: How do you know you "ran the car almost empty"?  I would monitor my gas mileage on a full tank and see if it is consistent with burning almost 13 gallons when the fuel gauge *reports* that the tank is empty.

Comment: It is normal for it to stop 1/2 gallon before overflowing.  You want gas in the tank, not sitting in the fill hose and check valves.  There was a question previously that said overfilling your tank can damage your charcoal canister.  The gauge is likely set up so even if it appears you have nothing left at all, you still have a gallon or so left.  This is to help people from running out by making them think they have less than they actually do.  The only way to truly know is to drive it until you run out.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've picked up a pretty massive dent in your tank. Can you see underneath it well enough to determine if this is the case?

Comment: No there is no dent

Answer (score 1):

A lot of vehicles today have a check valve that prevents them from leaking fuel out the fill port in case the vehicle rolls-over. Depending on the exact design of the check valve, some of them cause difficulty filling-up. Also, different fuel station pumps flow at different rates, not only because of design, but also because of the fuel level in the underground tanks.

If your filling problem is not new, this is likely the cause of it. Just fill slower, a lot slower. And take little 5-10 second breaks when the pump stops. Try a different fuel station, see if your Sentra likes their pumps better. I onced leased a 2010 Sentra and it always had this problem, solve it by filling much slower and avoiding some fuel stations.

If your filling problem is new, investigate as has been suggested in the comments:

1. Get your tank filled to the brim
2. Reset your trip odometer
3. See how many miles you get from a full tank
4. Look at what your fuel gauge is reading from time to time

It could be an electrical trouble (loose connection) with the fuel sensor, or the floater gets stuck somewhere. Most cars have an access hatch under the rear seat. Do not do this with a full tank, your car will stink of gas for a good long time, not to mention the fire risk.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Technical Service Bulletin issued by Nissan that applies to many of their vehicles not being able to be filled.  Take it to the dealer and they'll hopefully replace your breather valve and hose.